# struts2 Passing Array with null

Tags: java, struts2

I'm working on fixing a legacy system using struts2, and found this odd behavior where when passing arrays (from html form submit), the values with null/empty get removed from the array. It happens on a Integer[] type, but not with String[].

example:

```
<s:form action="test">
   <s:textfield name="arr" value="1"/>
   <s:textfield name="arr" value=""/>
   <s:textfield name="arr" value="2"/>
</s:form>
```

it will only return {1,2}, instead of {1,null,2}, is there any workaround this?

Comment: Depending on exactly what HTML is generated, this may be happening in the browser.  I suggest you examine the rendered form with the browser's debug console and check what is actually being sent over the wire on submit.

Comment: @JimGarrison how would you do this?

Comment: Search the web for documentation on your browser's debug console capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out we had a struts filter that skips all empty values which other functions relied upon so I can't simply remove it...

so i ended up adding a script to change all null to -1 before passing the params, not a good solution but its sufficient